# If $f(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ and $x=\frac{1}{2^n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer, and $f(x)=0$ for all other values of $x$. Is $f$ continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Just started Taylors "Advanced Calculus", which seems moderately proof based. I can't figure this one out. The book is old, so some of the notation is a bit odd to my eyes.

Regardless, I start by rearranging $x=\frac{1}{2^n}$ into $\log_2(\frac{1}{x})=n$. From this it follows that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\log_2(\frac{1}{x})}$, which tends to $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

So, from this I would assume that it is in fact not continuous as it seems to not be defined at $0$. However, when I check the answer in the back of the book, it simply states that it is. For some problems the book will show a method, however, unfortunately that was not the case for this one.

Comment: I suggest you start by writing the definition for continuity at $x=0$ and then try and work from there.

Comment: "If $f(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ and $x=\frac{1}{2^n}$" That's not well written. I think you mean  "If $f(1/2^n)=1/n,$ ...

Answer (score 1):

We want to estimate $|f(x)|$ in a neighbourhood of $0$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $\delta=\varepsilon$, then if $1/\delta<n$, then $1/\varepsilon=1/\delta<n\leq 2^n$. It now follows that if $1/n<\delta$, then $1/2^n<\varepsilon$. Now for $|x|<\delta$ we either have $x=1/n$ for some $n$ in which case $|f(x)|=1/2^n<\varepsilon$, if not then $|f(x)|=0<\varepsilon$.